# Remap rotation matrix to different axis system

Tags: android, matrix, ogre3d, remap

I am using an adapted version of android's [getRotationMatrix](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getRotationMatrix%28float%5B%5D,%20float%5B%5D,%20float%5B%5D,%20float%5B%5D%29) in a c++ program that reads the phone's sensor data over the network and calculates the device's matrix.

The function works fine and calculates the device's orientation. Unfortunately, Ogre3d has a different axis system than the device. So even though rotation about the x-axis works fine, the y and z axis are wrong. Holding the device level and pointing to north (identity matrix). When I pitch, the rotation is correct. But when I roll and yaw the rotations are alternated. Roll is yaw in Ogre3d and vice versa.

```
    (Ogre3d)                         ([Device][5])

   ^ +y-axis                       ^ +z-axis                                  
   *                               *                                 
   *                               *                                 
   *                               *    ^ +y-axis                             
   *                               *   *                               
   *                               *  *                                
   *                               * *                                 
   ************> + x-axis          ************> +x-axis                      
  *                                                                   
 *                                                                    
v +z-axis
```

A quick look at the two axis system looks like Ogre's system (on the left) is essentially the device's system rotated 90 degrees counter clockwise about the x-axis.

I tried to experiment with various combinations when I fist assign sensor values before the matrix is calculated but no combination seems to work correctly. How would I make sure that the rotation matrix getRotationMatrix() produces displays correctly on Ogre3D?

For Reference here is the function that calculates the matrix:

```
bool getRotationMatrix() {
    //sensor data coming through the network are 
    //stored in accel(accelerometer) and mag(geomagnetic)
    //vars which the function has access to
    float Ax = accel[0]; float Ay = accel[1];   float Az = accel[2];
    float Ex = mag[0];   float Ey = mag[1];     float Ez = mag[2];

    float Hx = Ey * Az - Ez * Ay;
    float Hy = Ez * Ax - Ex * Az;
    float Hz = Ex * Ay - Ey * Ax;
    float normH = (float) Math::Sqrt(Hx * Hx + Hy * Hy + Hz * Hz);
    if (normH < 0.1f) {
        // device is close to free fall (or in space?), or close to
        // magnetic north pole. Typical values are  > 100.
        return false;
    }
    float invH = 1.0f / normH;
    Hx *= invH;
    Hy *= invH;
    Hz *= invH;
    float invA = 1.0f / (float) Math::Sqrt(Ax * Ax + Ay * Ay + Az * Az);
    Ax *= invA;
    Ay *= invA;
    Az *= invA;
    float Mx = Ay * Hz - Az * Hy;
    float My = Az * Hx - Ax * Hz;
    float Mz = Ax * Hy - Ay * Hx;

    //ogre3d's matrix3 is column-major whereas getrotatinomatrix produces
    //a row-major matrix thus i have tranposed it here
    orientation[0][0] = Hx; orientation[0][2] = Mx; orientation[0][2] = Ax;
    orientation[1][0] = Hy; orientation[1][3] = My; orientation[1][2] = Ay;
    orientation[2][0] = Hz; orientation[2][4] = Mz; orientation[2][2] = Az;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Just wondering, is it legal to use code ported code from Android like that? I wish I understood the meaning behind the math (which I presume is not IP) so that I could write it on my own.

Comment: Of course it's legal.
acc = data from accelerometer
ma = data from magnetic sensor. 

Here's the Ogre3D functions, it think it's pretty straightforward: 

Vector3 H = ma.crossProduct(acc);
float normH = (float) H.length();
float invH = 1.0f / normH;

H *= invH;

float invA = 1.0f / (float) acc.length();

acc *= invA;

Vector3 M = acc.crossProduct(H);

orientation[0][0] = H.x;   orientation[0][1] = H.y;   orientation[0][2] = H.z;
orientation[1][0] = M.x;   orientation[1][1] = M.y;   orientation[1][2] = M.z;
orientation[2][0] = acc.x; orientation[2][1] = acc.y; orientation[2][2] = acc.z;

Comment: True, but we just took the Java code from Android and converted to C++. Is that legal? Shouldn't we have written the code from scratch or have come up with it entirely by ourselves?

Comment: But the method is a very well known method of determining orientation based on two known vectors from 1968. Google does not own any patents or rights on that method. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triad_Method

Comment: The problem isn't the method. It's the fact that the code is derived from the one Google owns.

Comment: Google doesn't own anything. Android is open source under the Apache v2 open source license.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. In my function the unit vectors calculated after the cross products I put them in columns whereas I should be putting them in the rows in their appointed matrix3 cells as usual. Something about row-major and column-major confused me even though I was referring to the elements in 2d [][].

multiplying the outcome of the matrix calculation function with this matrix:

1  0  0

0  0  1

0 -1  0

Then pitching the whole result by another p/2 about axis solved the remap problem but I fear my geometry is inverted.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just add the one additional rotation you've already identified before you use it in ogre?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Matrix Rotation, but if the Systems rotates like you are showing, I think that youshould do the following:

X Axis stays the same way, so:

```
float Ax = accel[0];
float Ex = mag[0];
```

Y Axis in (Ogre3d) is Z axis in ([Device][5]), so:

```
float Ay = accel[2];
float Ey = mag[2];
```

Z Axis in (Ogre3d) is the oposite of Y axis in ([Device][5]), so:

```
float Az = accel[1] * (-1);
float Ez = mag[1] * (-1);
```

Try that

Comment: I have already tried that. I tried it again and unfortunately it doesn't work :/ It does switch y with z but the rotation on the z axis is reversed and no matter what combination I try I can't get it right (been trying for several days now). Thank you though! I appreciate the help.